# in java add column to dataframe using withColumn looking up field value in a map

Tags: apache-spark

In Java I want to add a column to a dataframe with the value looked up in a map using the value from a column, like this

```java
.withColumn( "lookup" , lit( sizes.value( ).floorEntry( col( "integer" ) ).getValue( ) ) )
```

but this results in an exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.Column cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
        at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1290)
```

If I use a fixed value for the key the lookup works

```java
.withColumn( "lookup" , lit( sizes.value( ).floorEntry( 28 ).getValue( ) ) )
```

Is what I am attempting possible?

Note that the map is a 'NavigableMap' to get closest matches, and it has been broadcast.

The code with the problem line commented out

```java
    final Broadcast< NavigableMap > sizes = spark.sparkContext( )
        .broadcast(
            new NavigableMapBuilder<Integer, Integer>()
                .put( 13, 8000 )
                .put( 16, 6905 )
                .put( 27, 1894 )
                .put( 29, 2107 )
                .get() ,
            classTag( NavigableMap.class )
        );

    final Dataset< Row > extract = spark.createDataFrame(
        asList(
          create( "C000001573", new Date( 119, 8 ,13 ) , 13 ),
          create( "C000001573", new Date( 119, 8 ,14 ) , 16 ),
          create( "C000001573", new Date( 119, 8 ,15 ) , 27 ),
          create( "C000001573", new Date( 119, 8 ,16 ) , 29 )
        ) ,
        DataTypes.createStructType(
            new StructField[] {
              DataTypes.createStructField( "key", DataTypes.StringType, false),
                DataTypes.createStructField( "date", DataTypes.DateType, false),
                DataTypes.createStructField( "integer", DataTypes.IntegerType, false)
            }
        )
    );

    extract
        .withColumn( "multiply" , col( "integer" ).multiply( 10 ) )
//        .withColumn( "lookup" , lit( sizes.value( ).floorEntry( col( "integer" ) ).getValue( ) ) )
        .withColumn( "lookup" , lit( sizes.value( ).floorEntry( 28 ).getValue( ) ) )
        .withColumn( "copy" , col( "date" ) )
        .show();
```

and

```java
public class NavigableMapBuilder<K, V> {

  private final NavigableMap<K, V> map = new TreeMap<>();

  public NavigableMapBuilder<K,V> put( K key, V value) {
    this.map.put(key, value);
    return this;
  }

  public NavigableMap<K, V> get() {
    return this.map;
  }
}
```

which generates this output

```
+----------+----------+-------+--------+------+----------+
|       key|      date|integer|multiply|lookup|     extra|
+----------+----------+-------+--------+------+----------+
|C000001573|2019-09-13|     13|     130|  1894|2019-09-13|
|C000001573|2019-09-14|     16|     160|  1894|2019-09-14|
|C000001573|2019-09-15|     27|     270|  1894|2019-09-15|
|C000001573|2019-09-16|     29|     290|  1894|2019-09-16|
+----------+----------+-------+--------+------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a user defined function: I referenced Apache Spark in Action version 2 MEAP for this.

The function

```java
import org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast;
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF1;

import java.util.NavigableMap;

public class SizeLookup implements UDF1<Integer,Integer> {

  private final Broadcast< NavigableMap > sizes;

  public SizeLookup(Broadcast< NavigableMap > sizes ){
    this.sizes = sizes;
  }

  @Override
  public Integer call( Integer key ) {
    return (Integer)sizes.value( ).floorEntry( key ).getValue( );
  }
}
```

The code example updated to use it

```java
    final Broadcast< NavigableMap > sizes = spark.sparkContext( )
        .broadcast(
            new NavigableMapBuilder<Integer, Integer>()
                .put( 13, 8000 )
                .put( 16, 6905 )
                .put( 27, 1894 )
                .put( 29, 2107 )
                .get() ,
            classTag( NavigableMap.class )
        );

    spark.udf().register( "lookupSize", new SizeLookup( sizes ) , DataTypes.IntegerType );

    final Dataset< Row > extract = spark.createDataFrame(
        asList(
          create( "C000001573", new Date( 119, 8 ,13 ) , 13 ),
          create( "C000001573", new Date( 119, 8 ,14 ) , 14 ),
          create( "C000001573", new Date( 119, 8 ,15 ) , 27 ),
          create( "C000001573", new Date( 119, 8 ,16 ) , 29 )
        ) ,
        DataTypes.createStructType(
            new StructField[] {
              DataTypes.createStructField( "key", DataTypes.StringType, false),
                DataTypes.createStructField( "date", DataTypes.DateType, false),
                DataTypes.createStructField( "integer", DataTypes.IntegerType, false)
            }
        )
    );

    extract
        .withColumn( "multiply" , col( "integer" ).multiply( 10 ) )
        .withColumn( "lookup" , callUDF( "lookupSize", col( "integer" ) ) )
        .withColumn( "copy" , col( "date" ) )
        .show();
```

This was easy to implement. Apparently it can be used in spark sql as well but I haven't tried.